# Uploadthing deleting files

Tags: next.js

How can I delete files from UploadThing? (NextJS 13)

Currently I try it like this:

-> src/server/delete.ts

```
import { UTApi } from "uploadthing/server"

export const utapi = new UTApi();
```

-> src/server/deleteImage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { utapi } from './delete'

const deleteImage = () => {

    const testDelete = async () => {
        console.log("delete files")
        const res = await utapi.deleteFiles("b0e3a5bc-dd85-40fe-9a0c-59d2ece0bb60-4ulhix.png");
        console.log(res)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>test image delete</h1>
            <button onClick={testDelete}>Delete files</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default deleteImage
```

I then try to call it from a client component like this:

```
<DeleteImage />
```

However, I get the error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: The `utapi` can only be used on the server."

Are there any good examples on how to delete files on uploadthing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
  export const { GET, POST } = createNextRouteHandler({
  router: ourFileRouter,
});

export async function DELETE(request: Request) {
  const data = await request.json();
  const newUrl = data.url.substring(data.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  const utapi = new UTApi(); --- i used this inside route file in uploadthing folder
  await utapi.deleteFiles(newUrl);

  return Response.json({ message: "ok" });
}
```

this is my delete function in client component:

```
const deleteValue = async () => {
    await axios.delete("api/uploadthing", {
      data: {
        url: value,
      },
    });
  };
```